# Flow: Promise incompatible with array type in async function

Tags: javascript, flowtype

In my async function, which makes an API call to get a list of filters, I get the following flow error:

Cannot return array literal because `Promise` [1] is incompatible with array type [2].

It appears when doing either of the possible returns.

Could somebody please explain why I'm getting it?

Tried using a try/catch block, both around the entire contents of the function and just around the await statement, returning [] upon the catch.

Unsure why it would think I am returning a promise, if I catch any possible rejections. What am I missing, here?

```js
getSavedFilters: (void) => Array<SavedFilter> = async () => {
    const savedFiltersResponse = await CaseApi.listSavedFilters();

    if (savedFiltersResponse.type === 'Failure') return [];
    return savedFiltersResponse.filters;
};
```

Comment: i think your problem is because of  `const savedFiltersResponse` yout error itself saying that you can not assign object to array , make array to object `{}` it will get resolve

Answer (score 4):

All async functions return promises. The promise will resolve to whatever you return. So since you're returning an array with your code, the appropriate type definition is:

```
getSavedFilters: (void) => Promise<Array<SavedFilter>> = async () => {
 // ... etc
```

Comment: Ah! I didn't realize that what the async function return type WAS a promise, because I expected that the resolution happened before the return.

Thanks for the help!